# Как вернутся к нужному элементу Listview?

Tags: android, listview, прокрутка

К примеру, есть список из 200 элементов. 
Пользователь отмотал 150 позиций вниз и кликнул на элементе, перешел внутрь, прочитал информацию, и хочет выйти, чтобы зайти, прочитать информацию о 151 элементе. Но по кнопке назад и домой возвращается к началу списка, т.е. надо снова мотать вниз.

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку домой или назад открывалась активити listview именно на той позиции, с которой был осуществлен переход.

Пробовал вот так:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

int n = 0; // сюда передавал обратный интент с путом айди элемента списка.
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(n);
```

Не работает.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014089/maintain-save-restore-scroll-position-when-returning-to-a-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментарии дали правильный ответ, правда пришлось сделать поле статиком, чтобы заработало:

```
static Parcelable state;

@Override
public void onPause() {    
    // Save ListView state @ onPause
    Log.d(TAG, "saving listview state @ onPause");
    state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();
    super.onPause();
}
...

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Set new items
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
    // Restore previous state (including selected item index and scroll position)
    if(state != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "trying to restore listview state..");
        listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }
}
```